# How to deal with optional attached property and designer issues?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, attached-properties

I've created an new style for a `TextBox` with a custom control template. At the control template I've binding to an (for my case) optional attached property. So running my application with the control works fine, but the visual studio designer shows me some error messagen when the attached property is now defined at one control.

> Property path is not valid. 'TextBox' does not have a public property named 'CustomCommand'.

The binding is defined as the following:

```
Command="{Binding Path=(attachedProperties:TextBox.CustomCommand), TargetNullValue={x:Null}, FallbackValue={x:Null}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}"
```

Is there any best practice how to deal with some optional bindings to an attached property?

Comment: Is it due to name? Try to rename `TextBox` to `TextBoxBehaviors`, is error still?

Comment: Did you try a clean build and a VS restart? If it works fine at runtime, the designer is just having a bad day, as it often does.